# Creating the chart from database data .The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm working on an MVC Application i want to display a graph that will show how many Loads per Company i have on the database.

[image: The entity or complex type 'EMIS.Models.Report' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query error message]

The Generator in **Report model** is the CompanyName in **Loads model**.

**This my action method in the controller**

```
public ActionResult GetLoadsPieChart()
    {
        IQueryable<Report> data = from cust in db.Loads
                                  group cust by cust.CompanyName into provGroup
                                  select new Report()
                                  {

                                      Generator = provGroup.Key,

                                      CountLoad = provGroup.Count(),

                                      Percentage = ((provGroup.Count() * 100) / (db.Loads.Count()))
                                  };


        ArrayList xValue = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList yValue = new ArrayList();

        var results = data;

        results.ToList().ForEach(rs => xValue.Add(rs.Generator));
        results.ToList().ForEach(rs => yValue.Add(rs.CountLoad));

        var key = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400, theme: ChartTheme.Blue);
        key.AddSeries(chartType: "column", xValue: xValue, yValues: yValue);
        key.AddTitle("LOADS STATISTICS PER GENERATOR");
        key.Write("png");
        return null;

    }
```

**Report model**

```
public class Report
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Generator { get; set; }

    public int CountLoad { get; set; }

    public int Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

**Load model**

```
public class Load
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int LoadNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Generator")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Truck")]
    public string NumberPlate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Vehicle Size/ Capacity")]
    public string VehicleSize { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "PH")]
    public int PH { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Amount")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Penalty Amount")]
    public decimal PenaltyAmount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Load Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime LoadDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Generator> Generator { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried to follow some solutions of the same error but it couldn't help. Please help!!!!

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eDgnqH . working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Var data = (from cust in db.Loads
                                  group cust by cust.CompanyName into provGroup
                                  select new 
                                  {

                                      Generator = provGroup.Key,

                                      CountLoad = provGroup.Count(),

                                      Percentage = ((provGroup.Count() * 100) / (db.Loads.Count()))
                                  }).ToList();


        ArrayList xValue = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList yValue = new ArrayList();



        Data.ForEach(rs => xValue.Add(rs.Generator));
        Data.ForEach(rs => yValue.Add(rs.CountLoad));

        var key = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400, theme: ChartTheme.Blue);
        key.AddSeries(chartType: "column", xValue: xValue, yValues: yValue);
        key.AddTitle("LOADS STATISTICS PER GENERATOR");
        key.Write("png");
        return null;
```

First I am typing this in mobile so you might have to tweak a bit. First what you doing here is writing a projection query into a custom object `Report`

As this query was a queryable you are then executing is when you do ToList. But in your code you are never using the report model directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped @Preet , you are life saver.